# I am a begineer in Azure ARM Templates.I need to learn ARM

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Can any please guide me the basic pre-requisite to learn. I have gone through various links under MSFT Azure Documentation like:
1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-quickstart-create-templates-use
2) Have downloaded various templates from Azure portal and tried to edit with VS code. When I start editing the VS code, the problem which I have
is lack of knowledge for the values which can be passed or which values I can play with at specific piece of code.

```
Below is the sample template

{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_ZRS",
        "Premium_LRS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage Account type"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "storageAccountName": "[concat('store', uniquestring(resourceGroup().id))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-07-01",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "properties": {}
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
    }
  }
}
```

In the above template, I am struggling to get the insights what can be added/edited.Also how these functions are added "[concat('store', uniquestring(resourceGroup().id))" is there any list for this?

3) Also, how can I integrate/ call  multiple parameters or variables into a template.

Comment: also consider creating Azure resources with Azure CLI. It can be easier and better to read than ARM Templates for certain/many cases

Answer (score 2):

[ARM Template function reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions). [VS Code extension for ARM Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msazurermtools.azurerm-vscode-tools).

for multiple parameters\variables, just define them in the template. There is a [repo with lots of examples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) you can draw inspiration from. And a [template reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates), but I'd rather use rest api reference. its more reliable

Comment: I have gone through these links, However I am looking to create a simple template from scratch so that I can have a better idea to play with. Is there any videos/documentation link available for this?

Comment: Best place is to go through azure ARM template documentation. There you can find what each function is doing

Comment: Lets assume that I need to create a simple storage account/VM from my Own, how can i do it without copy and paste from internet. I have VS code and the ARM template extension is installed in it.So how can I leverage the VS code and would be the key parameters/function and variables should be created?

Comment: that extension has got intellisense

Comment: is there anyway where I can show my POC so that I can let you know guys about the queries/dobuts.

Comment: sure, you can create additional question here while you go, so as soon as you have a question - create a new question - I'll pick it up quite fast

Answer (score 0):

I found a great repo for this on **GitHub**. here you can find different examples for all components (**https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates**).

I hope these examples help you further.

Comment: like literally the same link that I posted. you have to be kidding me

Answer (score 0):

I learn (and still learning) using these sites:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates

And this other, was free in one moment: 
https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/microsoft-azure-resource-manager-mastering

Use Visual Studio Code, with extensions for Azure Resource Manager Tools and Azure CLI Tools.